# Getting Cell Information From Database Without Using While Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying learn a more efficient way of getting cell data without having to use a while loop. Here's what I mean.

This is what I would normally do for each piece of information I need:

```
$getName1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM livestreams WHERE stream_number='1'");

while($nameRow1 = mysqli_fetch_array($getName1)) {
  $playerName1 = $nameRow1['stream_name'];
}
```

But I have a ton of rows I need to do this for and I only need the "stream_name" for each row.  I'm looking for a way to grab the stream_name from a specific row without having to do a while loop each and every time. And I need to display this information.

Comment: I don't get your question. Here, in `while` loop you assign `$playerName1` each iteration. Just simply remove `while`.

Comment: Can you have more than one result when you run your query?

Comment: why not just select all the rows you are interested in one query then process them in php instead of performing a separate select for each item. That would provide a much bigger performance gain than worrying about the while

Comment: don't think `while` is your real problem...

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can first limit your select to only the field you need like `SELECT stream_number FROM` instead of selecting all table's field `SELECT * FROM` as you did. The while loop is not a problem in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is not the problem. Your query can be adjusted to perform better. Only fetching the column you want.

```
"SELECT stream_name FROM livestreams WHERE stream_number='1'"
```

Comment: Okay, if I adjust my query to what you stated, how would I then display the information from that query?

Comment: But that wouldn't make sense because the SELECT would already know the exact cell i'm talking about, then in the while loop I say $variable['stream_name']?

Comment: You will get a associative array like in your example but only index `stream_name` will be populated. If you select with `*` **all** column will be retrieved from the database and the array will be populated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable like

```
$stream_number='1' //dynamic variable
$getName1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT stream_name FROM livestreams WHERE stream_number='.$stream_number.'");
while($nameRow1 = mysqli_fetch_array($getName1)) {
  $playerName1 = $nameRow1['stream_name'];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Make a custom function that will execute the query for you and return only the array of stream name thats it.